# Javascript onclick function undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have problem with onclick function

My link

```
<a id="reply" onclick="replyFunction({{$review->id}})"class="right-button">Reply</a>
```

Function:

```
function replyFunction(id){
  $('#reply').closest('div').append( $('.replyform'));
  $('.replyform').show();
  $('.replyform').attr('action', "/reply/submit/" + id);              
}
```

Somehow this doesnt work I am getting

> (index):155 Uncaught ReferenceError: replyFunction is not defined
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

I have included the file and it should work i think.

What I am trying to do is to pass id to the function. Basically a user presses reply button onclick function should send parent id and with javascript I should change form that user will fill action with the parent id so I get the right route (I am working with laravel).

P.S. If there is an easier way to do this that I am missing would be glad to hear it.

Comment: Place your script inside the body tag. `<script>function replyFunction(id){ }</script>`

Comment: "I have included the file and it should work i think." you have to be sure before asking. Please check your browser's developer console.

Comment: Have you defined `replyFunction()` within another function? Such as a jQuery document.ready event handler? If so, that's the problem. It needs to be at global level. Also note that using `on*` event attributes is an outdated bad practice which should be avoided. Use unobtrusive event handlers instead.

Comment: I am using a different file and I include it before </body> tag, I tried alerting in that file outside the function and it worked.

Comment: For this to work, the function must be known already at the point where the browser encounters this HTML element - meaning, you can not embed the script only later on, further down the page. But since you are using jQuery already, you should do this properly to begin with - use its methods to bind the event handlers, and put the id you need into a custom data attribute, so that the handler function can read it from there. And btw., using a link for this is rather wrong as well - if it doesn’t _link_ anywhere, and is only used to trigger functionality via JS, then it should be a _button_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your are using jQuery anyway you should set the eventlistener there. And as replyFunction is a callback, it will get an event as parameter and not the given value.

You should

```
<div>
  <a id="reply" data-reviewId="{{$review->id}}" class="right-button">Reply</a>
</div>
```

and

```
(function ($) {
    $('#reply').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // do not follow the link or move to top
        var replyId = $(this).attr('data-reviewId');
        $(this).closest('div').append( $('.replyform'));
        $('.replyform')
            .show()
            .attr('action', "/reply/submit/" + replyId);
    })
})(jQuery);
```

**BUT** Thats not what you intend to do, I guess. I updated the codepen.

If you want to add a form and dynamically change its action you should clone a dummy and add it to the desired place, if there are more than one form on the page. If there is only one form, you can give it an id and change the attribute via the id.

Comment: Thanks can call function now but somehow it did not change the attribute

Comment: i updated the script again, maybe you forgot to wrap your function into that self-executing function!?

Comment: It worked, I am sorry for not coming back here completely forgot it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could do it only on the script side:

```
var reply = document.getElementById("reply"); // $("#reply")
var review = document.getElementById("review"); // $("#reply")
```

And then reference your function onclick

```
reply.onclick = () => { replyFunction(review); };
```